# How to Upload Multiple image into database for same id and show into gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload multiple images for the same id, I do my self but the problem is that they get only last image which I selected so that when we try to show the code will display the same image in all.

Here my code,

```
DataClassesDataContext dc = new DataClassesDataContext();
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
    DataSet ds1 = new DataSet();

protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        imgError.Visible = false;
        int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ERID"].ToString());
        foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        {
            if ((postedFile != null) && (postedFile.ContentLength > 0))
            {
                int iFileSize = postedFile.ContentLength;
                if (iFileSize > 2097152)
                {
                    imgError.Visible = true;
                    imgError.Text = "File Size Must be 2MB or less than..!";
                }
                else if (iFileSize <= 2097152)
                {
                    imgError.Visible = false;
                    tmpSaveFile();
                }
            }
        }


        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select FileName,Path from TmpImageStore where ERID='" + id + "'", con);
            sda.Fill(ds1);

            GridView1.DataSource = ds1;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }

void tmpSaveFile()
    {
        int id = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["ERID"].ToString());
        foreach (HttpPostedFile postedFile in FileUpload1.PostedFiles)
        {
            int count = 0;
            var data = (from t in dc.SplitExpenses where t.ERID == id select t).ToList();

            string filename = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
            string newFileName = "", locationCode = "", filePath = "";


            if (data.Count > 0)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);

                for (int i = 1; i <= data.Count; i++)
                {
                    postedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/InvoiceUploads/") + "Invoice " + id + "_" + i + FileExtension);
                }

                foreach (var x in data)
                {
                    locationCode = x.Location_Code;
                    count = count + 1;
                    newFileName = "Invoice " + id + "_" + count + FileExtension;
                    filePath = Server.MapPath("~/InvoiceUploads/") + "Invoice " + id + "_" + count + FileExtension;

                    string contentType = postedFile.ContentType;
                    using (Stream fs = postedFile.InputStream)
                    {
                        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
                        {
                            byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);
                            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
                            {
                                con.Open();
                                string query = "insert into TmpImageStore (FileName,ContentType,Path,ERID)values('" + newFileName + "', '" + contentType + "', '" + filePath + "', '" + id + "')";
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                                adapter.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                                adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                                cmd.Dispose();
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

here i also provide my html code that my help you,

```
<div class="box">
                            <div class="box-header">
                                <h2>Invoice Upload
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="padding">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6 col-md-8">
                                        <div class="p-3">
                                            <ol class="breadcrumb white" style="color:#fd9c03;font-size:15px;padding:.20rem .5rem;">
                                                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i> Upload Upto 2MB Image/Document and must be use JPG/JPEG/PNG/PDF format!</li>
                                            </ol>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-6 col-md-6">
                                        <div class="p-3">
                                            <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-outline btn-rounded b-success text-success" AllowMultiple="true"/> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"
                                                ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage=" Invalid Image Format..!" ValidationExpression="^.+(.jpg|.JPG|.jpeg|.JPEG|.PNG|.png|.pdf|.PDF)$">
                                            </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                            <asp:Label ID="imgError" runat="server" Visible="false" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="Large"></asp:Label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-6 col-md-3">
                                        <div class="p-3">
                                            <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" OnClick="UploadFile" runat="server" Text="Upload" CssClass="md-btn md-raised mb-2 w-xs green" />
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowHeader="false">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Preview Image">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Path")%>'
                                                    Width="100px" Height="100px" Style="cursor: pointer" OnClientClick="return LoadDiv(this.src);" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </asp:GridView>

                            </div>
                        </div>
```

and yaa also there was another proble is that the image was not show in gridview and i know the problem is that they get full path of the image but when i customly provide the path like "~/InvoiceUpload/ABC_1.jpg" this will show me the image.

here my database tabe,

> ```
> CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TmpImageStore] (
>     [TI]          NUMERIC (18)   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
>     [FileName]    VARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
>     [ContentType] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
>     [Path]        VARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
>     [ERID]        NUMERIC (18)   NULL,
>     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TI] ASC)
> );
> ```

please anyone help me to resolved this.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You should create another table that has relationship with original table. For Example:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TmpImageStore] (
    [TI]          NUMERIC (18)   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [KeyA]        NUMERIC(18)
    [FileName]    VARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [ContentType] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Path]        VARCHAR (MAX)  NULL,
    [ERID]        NUMERIC (18)   NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TI] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test] (
    [KeyA]        NUMERIC (18)   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL
);
```